# How to update a claim when using Session Authentication Module (SAM)

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity

I'm using the Session Authentication Module to store the user claims in the authentication cookie.

What is the recommended approach to update the user's claims whilst they are logged in? An example would be if they update their profile (First Name/Last Name) and we want to update the associated claims.

I don't want to log the user out when this happens so `DeleteSessionTokenCookie` is not an option.

Comment: Using FederatedSignOut is an another possible way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037598/windows-identity-foundation-sign-out-or-update-claims

Comment: @DanilaPolevshikov I don't wish to sign the user out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a new session cookie with SAM.WriteSessionTokenToCookie.

Comment: When I do this the user is just logged out.

Comment: Brock pointed me in the right direction on Jabbr. I was not specifying the Auth Type when creating the updated `ClaimIdentity`.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail - how you fixed your problem? I am not sure what sessionToken I need to specify to the WriteSessionTokenToCookie call.

Answer (score 1):

Leastprivilege's answer is correct.

But in response to Vijay V's comment, here's example code on how to update the cookie after adding new claims to your claims principal:

```
var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
if (sam != null)
{
    var token = new SessionSecurityToken(claimsPrincipal);
    sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);
}
```

Pulled the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13674391).